# Apache Ignite persistent store recommended way for class versions

Tags: java, database, ignite, persistent

In RDBMS systems I can add new columns even when there is already data in a table. I wonder what is the suggested way doing this with Ignite persistent store when storing class objects?

If I have the following class with lots of data:

```
public class Person implements Serializable
{
  @QuerySqlField
  String firstName;

  @QuerySqlField
  String lastName;
}
```

And later I may want to add a new fields to this class, like

```
public class Person implements Serializable
{
  @QuerySqlField
  String firstName;

  @QuerySqlField
  String lastName;

  @QuerySqlField
  Date birthday;
}
```

Can I put and get old and new versions of this class without problem? What happens to the new field value when I read an old version of the class from the persistent store?

How will SQL queries work when the column birthday is not available in old versions of the data?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can put and get objects transparently after updating the class definition on client side. The only requirement is to NOT deploy this class on local classpath of server nodes.

SQL, however, will not pick this up automatically and annotation will not be processed in this case. To change SQL schema in runtime you need to use DDL commands (ALTER TABLE, CREATE IMDEX, etc.). More details here: https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/ddl

Comment: Thanks. Not deploying the class on the server node means the servers will use the old version of the class or they should not have any of these class definition at any time? Can you explain the reason?

Comment: @DonTequila Not deploying the class means that there is no class on server nodes at all, of any version. Ignite uses special binary format to store data that allows that: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/binary-marshaller

Comment: thanks for your answer again, but I'm still confused. Wouldn't server nodes exactly need these classes in order to work with them and computer jobs? Are you talking about pure database server nodes? So you suggest to keep DB server nodes separate from compute server nodes?

Comment: In compute you can use `BinaryObject` and `withKeepBinary()` (described on the same page).